# Add and increment number to the end of numerical or non-numerical string python

Tags: python, json, string

I am reading a JSON file with data in it and I am trying to ensure that each file that is created in my code has a unique value. However sometimes the value is a string either like "data" or some number as a string

So if the file I are creating 3 times is called "data", I want to convert it into:

```
data_0
data_1
data_2
```

Also if the value is the a number (but it string format) such as 145 I want to change that to:

```
145
146
147
```

Currently my code produces something like this:

```
data_0, 
data_0_1, 
data_0_1_2
```

or

```
145_0, 
145_0_1, 
145_0_1_2
```

Below is my code:

```
for index in range(0,len(test)):
      test[index]["value"]= test[index]["value"] + str(number)
```

I am using `str(number)` because otherwise I get this error:

> TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found

JSON file example:

```
"test": [{
    "type": "text",
    "value": "data"
}, {
    "type": "integer",
    "value": "145"
}]
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: add the content of `test` please.

Comment: @Borja I have added the content of test

Comment: @Borja It is a json file that I import and read in python, which is working correctly for me. That is the json format.

Comment: It's the first time you mention the word `json` in your post. Please, always be very specific.

Comment: Can you please clarify the question? What is wrong with your code? How would you like to improve it?

Comment: @Yaron My code produces data_0, data_0_1, data_0_1_2 or 145_0, 145_0_1,145_0_1_2 instead of producing data_0, data_1, data_2 or 145, 146, 147

Comment: At his time, your code produces `data0`, `data1`, if you want to get `data_0`, `data_1` you should use `test[index]["value"]= test[index]["value"] + "_" + str(number)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `try & catch` to check if the input is an integer or a string. If it's an `int` you sum 1 to the number, if it's a `string` you just append the `_index`.

```
test = [{"type": "text", "value": "data"}, {"type": "integer","value": "145"}]

for index in range(0,len(test)):
    try:
        # Test if the value is an integer
        test[index]["value"]= int(test[index]["value"]) + index

    except ValueError:
        # The value is an string
        test[index]["value"]= test[index]["value"] + "_" + str(index)

print test
```

Outputs:

```
[{'type': 'text', 'value': 'data_0'}, {'type': 'integer', 'value': 146}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Borja's answer is good and follows the [EAFP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python) principle. Your code can be cleaned up a little if you use `enumerate` and `str.format`.

```
for index, dictionary in enumerate(test):
    try:
        dictionary['value'] = int(dictionary['value']) + 1

    except ValueError:
        dictionary['value'] += '_{}'.format(index)
```